# Agda won't install

Tags: haskell, agda

I can't get Agda to install on Mac 10.9.2, Haskell platform 2013.2.0.0. When I run cabal install Agda, I get this.

```
39 warnings and 1 error generated.
Failed to install Agda-2.3.2.2
Updating documentation index /Users/me/Library/Haskell/doc/index.html
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Agda-2.3.2.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:  
ExitFailure 1
```

Any tips?

EDIT: After trying cabal-unpack etc as suggested, cabal-build gives this error:

```
src/full/Agda/Interaction/BasicOps.hs:3:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
     #-}
      ^
```

Comment: Try `cabal unpack Agda` then `cd Agda-*` and do the usual `cabal configure`, `cabal build`, `cabal install`.  This will give more detailed info, which you can post here and we can diagnose.

Comment: Mac 10.something stopped using gcc. The compiler (clang?) it uses doesn't play nice with CPP macros. Either get the patch on the haskell platform website or get gcc and tell ghc to use it.

Comment: Ok - running ghc clang patch fixed the problem - thanks! So this is the same issue as the question linked above, but there may be some value in leaving this question here to be found by people having Agda problems specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get things up and running, just move the #-} to the end of the line above....  Then do the usual cabal build, cabal install.  I don't have a mac here, so I can't test this myself, but I believe preprocessor directives need to be at the beginning of the line.  This is just a bandage, and might exist in other files.

Of course, the long term solution would be to file a bug report with Agda.